# Maven Selenium project Execution Not visible with Jenkins build Now

Tags: maven, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium maven project with Jenkins and when I run build now, execution is running in background for which I am able to see output in consol but my browser and all execution on browser is NOT visible. 
I tried searching around and change Jenkins service by checking allow window interaction checkbox but still not able to view it. I m running on window 10 and running with local(http://localhost:8080). I tried with Chrome, firefox & IE and all have same behavior of Not visible. 
I used command "mvn clean test" in Build - Execute Windows batch command.
Same project is running with Eclipse & CMD very well with visible execution.
I am using Jenkins version 2.46.3.
Anyone experienced this? Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of search & troubleshoot, I found solution as I installed Jenkins as Window version (.exe) so I uninstalled it and downloaded Jenkins from official jenkins website(https://jenkins.io/download/)  by clicking on Generic Java Package(.war) and then went into Command prompt and went to path where my Jenkins.war file dowloaded and install using java -jar jenkins.war and reregister with different accountname and password (created new account so it won't pull up the old account) and the Execution started DISPLAYING ON BROWSER. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Run Jenkins or slave from command line using war or jar provided, other option to try: check 'Allow service to interact with desktop' in Services.